# Rails, how to loop through a JSON object posted to the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

my app is posting a JSON object back to the server that is structured like so:

```
contacts:[{"id":38,"full_name":"xxxxxxx","email":""},{"id":70,"full_name":"xxxxxxx","email":""},{"id":79,"full_name":"xxxx","email":""},{"id":22,"full_name":"xxxxxxx","email":""},{"id":48,"full_name":"xxxxxx","email":""},{"id":69,"full_name":"xxxxx","email":""}]
```

How in the controller, can I loop through each of the records and get the record.id, record.full_name etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is basically how do I serialize this JSON string into a ruby object (hash). You would call `contacts=JSON.parse(json_string)` you can then call `contacts[0].id`, etc...

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work.     selectedContacts=JSON.parse(params[:contactsSelected])       selectedContacts.each do |contact|

      Rails.logger.info contact.full_name

    end

Comment: That errors NoMethodError (undefined method `full_name' for {"id"=>38,